# MSSQL замена значений в соседней ячейке

Tags: sql-server

Подскажите пожалуйста, как решить следующую задачу:
Если в одном из значений Null, то заменить все значения строки, кроме первого на null.
В интернете много примеров, как заменить сам Null, например:

```
select case
when fieldname is null then '123'
else fieldname end as fieldname
```

Но нет примеров как заменить соседнее значение

Пример на картинке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `UPDATE table SET [coll] = NULL WHERE [do] IS NULL;`

Comment: *например* Пример - дерьмо. `UPDATE table SET [fieldname] = COALESCE([fieldname], '123')`